# Help me avoid my memories from "going away"; how to "add ALL" to favorite memories rather than one at a time?

Tags: macos, photos, memory

I'm just starting to realize what macOS Photos is doing with memories. Apparently I have quite a lot of them already now!

Is there a way I can "add ALL to favorite memories" to avoid them from "going away"?

From [Quick Tip: How to Save your Memories Movies in Mac Photos](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/64277-save-your-memories-movies-in-mac-photos/):

> When you add a Memory to your Favorites, **you preserve it and keep it from going away** when Photos creates new Memories.

Right now I am double clicking each memory, then scrolling all the way to the bottom (past all the related memories) and clicking "add to favorite memories" one at a time, and looking for a save-all feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all memories to favorites using the following steps:

1. Click on the Memories tab
2. Click on an empty space in the memories panel
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all memories
4. Right click on any memory
5. Click on **Add to Favourite Memories**

[image: screenshot of Photos.app with instructions for adding all memories to favorites]

Here's a video demo: https://files.alinpanaitiu.com/add-all-memories-to-favorites.mp4

Comment: This is great news! I'll try it in the morning. This one may be harder: [How to merge most but not all photos from old laptop to new laptop?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/394836/143729)

Comment: Success! And a fairly obvious solution I should have guessed, as well as the dozens of others who read and didn't answer :-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rSQj.jpg